# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'uid')

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get list of pets that owned by current.user.uid but I am facing issues with the backend code. The error stated

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null
> (reading 'uid')

---

This my script

```
enter code here<script>

 // @ is an alias to /src
import getUser from "@/composables/getUser"
import { auth, db } from "@/firebase/config";
import {signOut} from "firebase/auth";
import { collection, onSnapshot, query, where  } from '@firebase/firestore';

export default {
 name: 'HomeView',
 setup(){

  const {user} = getUser()
  const router = useRouter()
  const q = query(collection(db,"pets"),where("UserID", "==", user.value.uid));
  const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q,(querySnapshot)=>{
  const pet = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=> {
    pet.push(...doc.data())
  });
  console.log("Current pets :", pet.join(","))
 })

  return {q, unsubscribe ,error}
 }
}
```

---

[firebase diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KP5pQ.png)

---

So, actually i want the document that have the current uid display in the list
thanks for helping me

Comment: It looks like `user.value` is null and you're trying to read property `uid` of it.

Answer (score 0):

You get the user from `const {user} = getUser()` which comes from `"@/composables/getUser"`.

Please share the code from the dependency as it sounds like the user object is not being provided at the time of execution. It could be due to two reasons:

1. The user is not logged in. In this case you would want to show the unauthenticated view.
2. The HomeView is rendering before the user state has been loaded. In this case you probably have a timing issue due to asynchronous code.

Typically you would use `onAuthStateChanged` to detect when a user logs in/out to update your application's state.

```
import { onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth"

onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  // Do something with user
  console.log(user.uid);
});
```